# How do i find if a whole word is in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.4

My code looks like this:

```
file = open('names.txt', 'r')
fileread = file.read()
loop = True
while loop is True:
    with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
        user_input = input('Enter a name: ')
        for line in f:
            if user_input in line:
                print('That name exists!')
            else:
                print('Couldn\'t find the name.')
```

The code basically asks the user for a name, and if the name exists in the text file, then the code says it exists, but if it doesn't it says it couldnt find it.

The only problem I have is that if you even enter part of the name, it will tell you the whole name exists. For example the names in my text file are: Anya, Albert and Clemont, all seperated on different lines. If i were to enter 'a' when prompted for user_input, the code will still say the name is present, and will just ask for another name. I understand why its doing this, because 'a' is technically in the line, but how do i make it so that it only says the name exists if they enter the whole thing? By whole thing i mean they enter for example 'Anya', rather than 'a' and the code only says the name exists if they enter 'Anya'. Thanks

Comment: the code could be a much simpler and much shorter. Use regexp approach

Comment: If the line `Ann Taylor` is in the file, is the name `Ann` in the file?

Comment: If i run the code (after adding the line Ann Taylor to the file), entering Ann when prompted returns that the name exists.

Comment: checking for user_input == line instead of user_input in line may solve your problem

Comment: I can't do that since this is sample code. I need a solution in another of my python files (i cant show due to confidentiality reasons) and in each line there is more than just the phrase. For example if the line contained: Clemont 12345 (which is similar to the other code i was talking about) then entering just Clemont wouldn't work

Comment: why you read the file multiples times? you already have the content in `fileread`, used that instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short solution using [***re.seach()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) function:

```
import re

with open('lines.txt', 'r') as fh:
    contents = fh.read()

loop = True
while loop:
    user_input = input('Enter a name: ').strip()
    if (re.search(r'\b'+ re.escape(user_input) + r'\b', contents, re.MULTILINE)):
        print("That name exists!")
    else:
        print("Couldn't find the name.")
```

Test cases:

```
Enter a name: Any
Couldn't find the name.

Enter a name: Anya
That name exists!

Enter a name: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question , just do equal comparison. Also noted that You have infinite loop , is that expected ? I changed the code to exit that loop when a matching name found in the file

```
file = open('inv.json', 'r')
fileread = file.read()
loop = True
while loop is True:
    with open('inv.json', 'r') as f:
        user_input = raw_input('Enter a name: ')
        for line in f:
            if user_input == line.strip():
                print('That name exists!')
                break
                #loop =False
            else:
                print('Couldn\'t find the name.')
```

Input

```
Anya
Albert
Clemont
```

Output

```
Enter a name: an
Couldn't find the name.
Couldn't find the name.
Couldn't find the name.

Enter a name: An
Couldn't find the name.
Couldn't find the name.
Couldn't find the name.

Enter a name: Any
Couldn't find the name.
Couldn't find the name.
Couldn't find the name.

Enter a name: Anya
That name exists!
```

Comment: Yeah it was intended to keep the loop; the code ive written up there is only sample code so i can understand a problem in another of my scripts.

Comment: ok :) in that case I will remove the  piece of code to exit the while loop